# I would like to reshape my data such that the individual items under the column ''variable'' become separate columns with their values under them

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

The current data looks like this: Please run the code below

```
df1<- data.frame(Names= c(c(rep("Lincon",12), rep("Joe",12),rep("Megi",12))),
                 Year= c(rep(c(rep(2002,4), rep(2003,4), rep(2004,4)),3)),
                 Values= c(c(c(600, 400,210, 41),c(450, 349, 250, 42), c(200, 300,150, 43), 
                         c(500, 436, 200, 52), c(820,480,400, 53), c(500, 210, 279,54),
                         c(701, 340, 112,45), c(195, 480, 120,46),c(550, 452, 111,47))),
                 Variables= rep(c("savings","food", "transport","age"),9))
```

however, I would like it to look like this with the corresponding values under the variables.
like this:

```
Names Year   savings   food   transport  age
```

1  Lincon 2002
2  Lincon 2002
3  Lincon 2002
4  Lincon 2002
5  Lincon 2003
6  Lincon 2003
7  Lincon 2003
8  Lincon 2003
9  Lincon 2004
10 Lincon 2004
11 Lincon 2004
12 Lincon 2004
13    Joe 2002
14    Joe 2002
15    Joe 2002
16    Joe 2002
17    Joe 2003
18    Joe 2003
19    Joe 2003
20    Joe 2003

Comment: Although I provided the answer, please see that this was already asked a zillion times in SO. THis type of operation is called a pivoting operation.

Answer (score 0):

use `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)

df1 |> 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Variables,
                values_from = Values)


# A tibble: 9 × 6
  Names   Year savings  food transport   age
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Lincon  2002     600   400       210    41
2 Lincon  2003     450   349       250    42
3 Lincon  2004     200   300       150    43
4 Joe     2002     500   436       200    52
5 Joe     2003     820   480       400    53
6 Joe     2004     500   210       279    54
7 Megi    2002     701   340       112    45
8 Megi    2003     195   480       120    46
9 Megi    2004     550   452       111    47
```